# Automatic logout in struts2

Tags: java, session, struts2

Please help me out, I am stuck at logic.

I have a table which contains the entry and exit time for a user, e.g.:

`userid -1001`

`entry time-11:00`

`exit time-11:30`

What I'm doing is, getting the entry and exit based on the login time, but what I want is once I have got the entry and exit slot ,I should be able to set the session logout time as the exit time stored in the table.

Suppose for: `user id -1001`, I should be able to logout user at 11:30.

Please help me how to achieve this

Comment: What part are you stuck on? How to end the user session?

Comment: Yes ,how to end the user session ,irrespective of the fact that whether user is performing any activity or user is idle ???

Comment: You will just have to use `session.invalidate()` to terminate a session, as the client may be busy you may be forced to clear the contents of the session by `calling session.clear()`. As for the time out issue there are some `jQuery` plugins which will do server callbacks for you so you can terminate the session if the user is idle. (I would recommend doing the time check in a filter)

Comment: Logically you can create a thread sleeping for the given time and kill the session after awakening.

Comment: Please put your efforts and use internet and start doing that. Please show us your efforts.

Comment: To Mr.Parth trivedi ,,,I am here to get help after browsing internet ,,please don't preach if you can't help ,because I can't find a single helping comment from your side like others,,,Moreover I am already working on a project thats why  such an issue has come up . thank you